dataframe union of filters and reduce the number of filters by merge
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'id'])
df['id'] = [i for i in range(len(df))]
df['A'] = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a3', 'a2', 'a1', 'a2']
df['B'] = ['b2', 'b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b2', 'b1']
df['C'] = ['c1', 'c3', 'c4' ,'c2', 'c1', 'c3', 'c2']
print(df)

list_dict_cols = [{'A': ['a1', 'a2'], 'B': ['b2']}, {'A': ['a1'], 'B': ['b3'], 'C': ['c2']}, {'C': ['c1']}]
df_res = pd.DataFrame()
for dict_cols in list_dict_cols:
    df_tem = df.copy()
    for  key, val in dict_cols.items():
        df_tem = df_tem[df_tem[key].isin(val)]
    df_res = pd.concat([df_res, df_tem])
    df_res.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

print(df_res)

I have some trades above with three categorical columns:
'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'B': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], 'C': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3' ,'c4']

Now I have some filters (each dict represents a filter that the values of key columns is in the value list):
list_dict_cols = [{'A': ['a1', 'a2'], 'B': ['b2']}, {'A': ['a1'], 'B': ['b3'], 'C': ['c2']}, {'C': ['c1']}]

I want to obtain the union of trades under those filters. Now I use the most naive way above by enumerating the filters and merging them and removing the duplicates.
Is there any generic way that first merge on the filers. For example,

if {'B': ['b2']} is in the filters, then we can discard any subset like  {'B': ['b2'], C: ['c2']}, etc,

if  {'A': ['a1'], 'B': ['b1']}, {'A': ['a1'], 'B': ['b2']}, {'A': ['a1'], 'B': ['b3']} are in, we can merge them as {'A': ['a1']}.


The goal for this is to reduce the filters since the real df may be very large. I know the result of merge is not unique, but could we simplify as more as possible.
